# If $P$ is a point on a rectangular hyperbola with center $C$ and foci $S$ and $S'$, then $SP \times S'P=(CP)^2$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

Is there a geometric proof to the statement below?

> If $P$ is a point on a rectangular hyperbola with center $C$ and foci $S$ and $S'$, then $SP \times S'P=(CP)^2$.

I am staring at the triangle $\Delta PS'S$ and the cevian $PC$. The expression above looks like it might have arrived from two similar triangles but alas $\Delta PS'C$ and $\Delta PSC$ don't look similar. I was also thinking about reflection property but don't know how it will be useful.

I know how to prove this analytically. I was wondering if there is a pure geometric way of proving it.

Comment: How do you tell apart, in this case, a "pure geometric" way from one that is not? You definitely need to use the property/definition of the rectangular hyperbola, so that if $\frac{PS - PS'}2= a$ and $CS'=c$, then $$2a^2 = c^2.$$This gives $$(PS-PS')^2 = 2(CS')^2.$$ If $H$ is the orthogonal projection of $P$ on $SS'$ you can probably reach your result using the former expression together with Pythagorean Theorem on $PSH$, $PS'H$, and $PCH$. Hope this helps in the direction you are looking at.